# issue when opening raster image in R, the pixel values a rescaled somehow

Tags: r, r-raster

I opened a Geotiff image in R using the raster function. However, the image seems to be rescaled. The minimum and maximum values should be 13607 and 15461 but are 275 and 305. The Geotiff image when opened in a GIS is correct but not in R.

This is my code:

Script:

```
library(raster)

trial<-raster("MOD11A2.A2000049.h17v05.006.2015058135048.tif", datatype = "INT2U")

trial

plot(trial)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the values you get with "R/raster" are correct. You are using the MODIS land surface temperature (LST) product, and the unit for LST is K (Kelvin). That makes the values provided by `raster` reasonable (a bit high for that time of the year, perhaps, but MODIS LST is not very reliable).

MODIS transforms the actual values to store them as 2-byte integers and thus reduce file size. I think you were expecting those transformed values, because that is what other software may give you. However, "raster" applies the `scale` of `0.02` to return the true values. As you can see [here](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mod11a1v006/), the valid range is

```
c(7500, 65535) * 0.02
#[1]  150.0 1310.7
```

Confirming that raster gets it right, and, I would argue, the other software does not.

I get similar values using the [luna](https://github.com/rspatial/luna) (on github) and terra (on CRAN) packages (here is a [manual for MODIS data](https://www.rspatial.org/terra/modis/1-introduction.html))

```
library(luna)
aoi <- c(-4.41, -3.59, 43.88, 44.31)
# you need a username and password for downloads
mf <- luna::getModis(product, start, end, aoi=aoi, download=TRUE,
                     path=".", username=user, password=pwd)
mf
# "./MOD11A2.A2000049.h17v04.006.2015058135051.hdf"

r <- rast(mf)
lst <- r[["LST_Day_1km"]]

# Kelvin to C
lst <- lst - 273.15
lst
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 1200, 1200, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 926.6254, 926.6254  (x, y)
#extent      : -1111951, 0, 4447802, 5559753  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs  
#data source : memory 
#names       : LST_Day_1km 
#min values  :       -3.95 
#max values  :       29.79
```